# Artifactory upload issue via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to upload a dummy file to artifactory via jenkins and its failing with below error

Is there a specific format the url needs to be given ?

```
[consumer_0] Deploying artifact: https://server/ABC-M-build/ndh/BDM/1/abc-1.zip
[consumer_0] An exception occurred during execution:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 403 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
org.artifactory.exception.CancelException: Artifact create not permitted without Group / Artifact / Version info Status code: 403 at
```

Comment: How do you deploy to Artifactory in Jenkins ? Using custom Jenkins plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the how the repo configured. Artifactory supports all the major tech stacks.

You need to check the repo settings(user should have admin access)

Also it will be worth to inform the how are you deploying the file is it via jenkins file or via the jenkins plugin of artifactory